# UISearchDisplayController search bar overlaps the label above in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

My view controller has a label on top that provides a description regarding the search to be performed. Below this label there is a UISearchDisplayController having a search bar that performs a search. This behaves normally without any issues in iOS 5 and 6. However in iOS 7, the search bar looks different. First of all, the search bar icon is placed in the centre of the search bar instead of being left aligned as it was in the case of iOS 5 and 6. Is this the default behaviour of search bar in iOS 7 ? This is my first question.

Now when I click inside the search bar, the search icon moves to the left, and the search bar enlarges itself, i.e an extra grey shaded view springs up above the search bar which overlaps the label above. Please observe the figure below to understand what I mean. My second question is this, Is this the default behaviour of search bar in iOS 7 ? Is there any way to get rid of this grey shaded view that comes above the search bar ? My opinion is this view is quiet unnecessary. Is there any property in search bar which I have to set in order to prevent this grey shade from appearing ? Or do I have to resize the search bar instead to avoid this ? Any suggestions from your side would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever get this answered?  I think the spring opening of the search bar is normal when you click on it.  I'm bothered as well by the grey shade.  Did you discover how to change this?  I've got black set for the underlying tableview.